# Tips to figure out meaning "as" when it means "when" or "because"

Tags: conjunctions

I would like to know some tips or hints to find a way to recognize whether "as" is using a meaning of "when" or a meaning of "because" when "as" connects two sentences.

For example, the sentence below which currently confuses me.

> The third point, where it is in our interests to engage directly with China in a constructive and positive way to shape China's actions and behaviors **as** they impact on the wider world.

In the above sentence, does "as" mean "because"?

addtion:
this sentence was from an interview script, so I cannot know if there is komma before "as".

But thanks for all comments.It seems this "as" doesn't mean "because".

Comment: No, more like *when* ... *at the time that*. Not sure it's a sentence. You don't need *positive* after you have "constructive."  You don't need *behaviors* if you have "actions."

Comment: IF there was a comma before ***as*** in your cited example, that would mean you should understand it as ***because***. Since there isn't, you should understand it as ***when = insofar as = in respect of the way = ...***

Comment: FF is certainly right that the default sense of 'as' here is not the 'because' (listing a reason) sense. But I'd say it's not the temporal sense either, which 'when' at least strongly suggests. I'd say 'insofar as' / 'inasmuch as' / 'to the extent that' is the sense in play here, different again.

Comment: I think "as" is normally used to mean something less definite than "because": either a temporal connection or a weak relationship, rather than a strong "if and only if" causal relationship.

Comment: "as" can have other meanings when connecting two clauses, e.g. the old commercial "Winston tastes good *as* a cigarette should." -- it means "in the way that" (the commercial contrasted this with the more common, but supposedly improper, use of "like" -- the tag line is "What do you want, good grammar or good taste?").

Comment: I would like to see the entire paragraph[,] as the quotation is only a sentence fragment.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to bear in mind *all* (reasonably common) senses of a word. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as) lists quite a few.

While 'as', as a conjunction, is certainly used

> (a)  to indicate that something happens during the time when something
> else is taking place.
>
> - *Frank watched him as he ambled through the crowd*
>
> Similar: while, just as, even as, at the (same) time that, at the
> moment that, during the time that, just when ... simultaneously

and

> (b) to indicate by comparison the way that something happens or is
> done.
>
> - *They can do as they wish*
> - [*Do as I do*] [[both senses, Oxford Languages Dictionary, courtesy of Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22as+meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&ei=6_fHZKS5BNmO8gKjsZWQBg&ved=0ahUKEwjk2rq1xLmAAxVZh1wKHaNYBWIQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=%22as+meaning&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiCyJhcyBtZWFuaW5nMgsQABiKBRixAxiRAjIFEAAYgAQyBRAAGIAEMgUQABiABDIFEAAYgAQyBRAAGIAEMgUQABiABDIFEAAYgAQyBRAAGIAEMgUQABiABEj6FlD5BljfE3ABeACQAQCYAXygAYsFqgEDNy4xuAEDyAEA-AEBwgIJEAAYBxgeGLADwgILEAAYigUYhgMYsAPCAgsQLhiDARixAxiABMICCBAAGIAEGLEDwgIFEC4YgATCAgsQLhiABBjHARjRA-IDBBgBIEGIBgGQBgo&sclient=gws-wiz-serp)]

as well as

> (c) to mean *because*:
>
> - *As it was getting late, I decided to book into a hotel.*

[[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/as)]

in this case, the most sensible interpretation involves another sense, 'inasmuch as' or 'addressing the way/s in which'. This sense has also been in common use for a long time:

> - *Women’s Interests:  International laws as they affect women*

[['New Age'; October 1904: Dora B. Montefiore](https://www.marxists.org/archive/montefiore/1904/10/law-women.htm)]

> - *Reviewing the Residence and Domicile rules as they affect the taxation of individuals*.

[[The National Archives; H M Treasury; Jan 2010](https://webarchive.nationalarchives.gov.uk/ukgwa/20100104181541/http://www.hm-treasury.gov.uk/bud_bud03_adres.htm)]

[The American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/as) perhaps gets closest here, though there is not an exactly parallel example sentence:

> *as* [1] ...
>
> 7. In accordance with which or with the way in which:
>
> - *The hotel is quite comfortable as such establishments go.*
> - *The sun is hot, as everyone knows.*

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question of how to know which a particular use is. But the answer to that is probably like most other ambiguities: whichever one makes most sense in the context.

Comment: ... And become more familiar with usages, over the decades, through reading reasonable examples and having conversations with practised Anglophones.. One first has to know about all the common usages, so of course the above is relevant, as it includes the one in question (which OP doesn't list; frame challenge answers are acceptable on ELU). The answer recommends further research. It also indicates the correct choice. All in all, a dialogue with a practised Anglophone.